# What does expect() do in rspec/cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, cucumber

In Michael Hartl's [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-features_and_steps), many examples use an `expect()` method. Here's one such example in a cucumber step definition:

```
Then /^she should see her profile page$/ do
  expect(page).to have_title(@user.name)
end
```

This same example can be written as such to the same effect:

```
Then /^she should see her profile page$/ do
  page.should have_title(@user.name)
end
```

Why use `expect()`? What value does it add?

Comment: http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax has a good description of both. There are subtle differences between expect() and .should, but both are useful if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a documentation on the rspec-expectations gem about this.
[Why switch over from should to expect](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/Should.md) Basically:

> should and should_not work by being added to every object. However, RSpec does not own every object and cannot ensure they work consistently on every object. In particular, they can lead to surprising failures when used with BasicObject-subclassed proxy objects.
>   expect avoids these problems altogether by not needing to be available on all objects.

A more detailed reasons for this is placed in: [RSpec's New Expectation Syntax](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax)

Answer (score 4):

`expect` is a bit more universal. You're passing an object or a block to rspec's `expect` method, rather than attempting to call a `should` method on objects that are outside of your control. As a result, `expect` is coming more and more into favor among developers.